# AngularJS - Conditionally display key and value if they exist

Tags: json, angularjs, href

This may be a little confusing to describe.

Basically, I am parsing multiple external JSON feeds that display in different views depending on the 'active tab' displayed. They both share the same partial template, so they both look exactly the same, just different content.

The problem that I am facing now is, that in some feeds, some keys are placed in an array and others are not.

For example, the feeds parses this kind of data:

JSON Feed 1 - One 'attributes' inside of 'link'

```
"link":{
  "attributes":{
    "href":"www.link1.com"
  }
}
```

JSON Feed 2 - Two 'attributes' inside of 'link'

```
"link":[
  {
    "attributes":{
      "href":"www.link1.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "attributes":{
      "href":"www.link2.com"
    }
  }
]
```

The only way I am able to get the value "www.link1.com" is via:

For Feed 1:

```
<a href="{{item['link']['attributes']['href']}}">link1</a>
```

And for Feed 2:

```
<a href="{{item['link'][0]['attributes']['href']}}">link1</a>
```

I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to do:

1) If `link[0]` exists - display it, else if `[link]` exists, display that instead.

2) Or if targeting the activeTab would be safer? For instance, if `activeTab = view2 or view4, use [link][0]`, `else if activeTab = view1 or view3 use [link]`, else if I do not want it to be displayed, do not display anything.

Also a relatable question, if I am on view2 can I only display `[link][0]` on that view?

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your model controller, you can reconstruct the JSON objects to make them similar. The value of `link` in both feeds should be an array.

Then in your template you can simply use [`ngRepeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) to get the items from inside the array.

Comment: Hi MK, I am a little lost. I am getting the JSON feed via a .factory being calling from inside my controller. From there, when the feed's view is shown, I am displaying (key,value) the inside of a ng-repeat inside of a <ul>. Is there another way without having to reconstruct the feed?

Comment: Curious, I can use activeTab in my controller to specify `ng-class` for elements, but not in ng-if statements like this "ng-if="activeTab == 'view1'"? Am I approaching the `ng-if` wrong? If so, I think this may help solve my issue of showing specific objects in different views.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - so I found a solution to one of the questions above: "How to only display [link][0] in a specific view"

Pro: It's a simple code that depends on the activeTab / view that is being displayed.

Con(?): Since I am really a newbie to AngularJS - not sure if this is the best solution.

Basically:
Depending on the ng-view that is currently displayed, than a specific JSON object will be displayed, such as:

```
<a ng-show="activeTab == 'view1' || activeTab == 'view3'" ng-href="{{item['link'][0]['attributes']['href']}}">
  <h6>Link1 from Feed2</h6>
</a>
```

---

Although the primary question is still unresolved: How to swap/switch JSON objects (key,values) if one exists, and not the other. I am still definitely trying to find a solution, although any help is still appreciated.

Please let me know what you think, or how I can improve the solution to the problem!

Thanks!
Roc.